# My React UI wont update unless i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello For some odd reason my React UI wont update. Im sure i implemented Router correctly and the URL actually changes to the routes but the UI wont update unless i refresh. I added Navigation.JS and App.js please let me know whats actually going on.

Thanks

Navigation.js

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Link,
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from "react-router-dom";

function Navigation(props) {
  return ( <
    Router >
    <
    div className = "Navigation" >
    <
    ul >
    <
    li >
    <
    Link exact to = "/" >
    Home <
    /Link> < /
    li > <
    li >
    <
    Link to = "/clock" > Clock < /Link> < /
    li > <
    li >
    <
    Link to = "/contact" > Contact < /Link> < /
    li > <
    li >
    <
    Link to = "/jeopardy" > Jeopardy < /Link> < /
    li > <
    /ul> < /
    div > <
    /Router>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
// import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import Welcome from "./components/welcome/Welcome";
import Clock from "./components/clock/Clock";
import Contact from "./components/contact/Contact";
import Navigation from "./components/navigation/Navigation";
import Jeopardy from "./components/jeopardy/Jeopardy";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation />
      <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Welcome {...props} component={Welcome} />} />
      <Route exact path="/clock" component={Clock} />
      <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      <Route exact path="/jeopardy" component={Jeopardy} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try to group your routes inside a [<Switch />](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)?

Comment: Also your router  is missing the `history` prop.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: How would i add that ? @BarryMichaelDoyle

Comment: I've added an answer...

Answer (score 4):

Firstly your `Navigation` rendering doesn't need to be wrapped in the `Router` tag. So make sure you remove that!

I'd also encourage wrapping the `Routes` in a `Switch` statement so that they don't show multiple pages for matching `paths`.

So change your `App` render to look like this.

```
<div className="App">
  <Router history={history}>
    <Navigation />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/clock" component={Clock} />
      <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      <Route exact path="/jeopardy" component={Jeopardy} />
      <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Welcome {...props} component={Welcome} />} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

Your router is also missing the `history` prop.

You can fix it by adding the following above your `App` function:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
// other imports go here

const history = createBrowserHistory()
```

Without adding the `history` prop, your router won't know to track your browser's `URL`.

Comment: Hi Im getting this error now 
.................................

./src/App.js
  Line 11:17:  'createBrowserhistory' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 13:1:   Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

Comment: I made a typo in my answer, fixed it.